# Mxarray error using set_param in Function Block Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I have a model which has 3 layers : Subsystem => 2 subsystems => 1 Matlab Function block (in each of both parent subsystem)
The input of the Function block can take the value : 1, 2 or 3 .
I have this code :

```
y = u;
coder.extrinsic('set_param','get_param','gcs');
parent = get_param(gcs,'parent');
parent2 = get_param(parent, 'parent');
Color = get_param(parent2, 'BackgroundColor');
if u == 3
     set_param(get_param(parent, 'parent'),'BackgroundColor','red');
elseif u == 2
    if Color == 'red'
    else
        set_param(get_param(parent, 'parent'),'BackgroundColor','orange');
    end
else
    if Color == 'red' || Color == 'orange'
    else
        set_param(get_param(parent, 'parent'),'BackgroundColor','green');
    end
end
```

**Explanation** :

When the block receive 3 the top Subsystem become red, 2 => Orange and 1 => Green

If he is already red he stay red, if he is already orange he can be red but not green.

**Error** : `Expected either a logical, char, int, fi, single, or double. Found an mxArray. MxArrays are returned from calls to the MATLAB interpreter and are not supported inside expressions. They may only be used on the right-hand side of assignments and as arguments to extrinsic functions.`

I don't understand why `Color` is not a string value as it originate from get_param function.

Thanks for help

Comment: For string comparisons, don't use numeric operators. `strcmp()` is what you need.

Comment: @Adriaan Even if i use `if strcmp(Color, 'red') == 1` it returns me same error

Comment: But works with `isequal()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with isequal()

```
if isequal(Color,'red') || isequal(Color,'orange')
```